# How to Fix UnboundLocalError at /signup/ in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-users

I Want To Create A User Like Signup or register when i hit submit button i got this error:

UnboundLocalError at /signup/

i want to signup user:

```
local variable 'usercustom' referenced before assignment
```

**here is my Views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
        custom_form = UserCustom(request.POST or None)

        if user_form.is_valid() and custom_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()

            custom = custom_form.save(commit=False)
            custom.user = user
            custom.save()

            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors,custom_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        usercustom = UserCustom()

    return render(request,'form.html',{'user_form':user_form,'usercustom':usercustom,'registered':registered})
```

**here is my Form.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}
      <div class="content-section">
        {% if registerd %}
          <h1>Thank Your For registering!</h1>
        {% else %}
          <h1>Register Here</h1>
          <h3>Fill out the form</h3>

          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ user_form.as_p }}
            {{ usercustom.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Register!" class="btn btn-danger">
          </form>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because usercustom is not declared when you tried to send POST request. You need to rename `custom_form` variable to `usercustom`. I have simplified your code for you.

```
def signup(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
        usercustom = UserCustom(request.POST or None)

        if user_form.is_valid() and usercustom.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()

            custom = usercustom.save(commit=False)
            custom.user = user
            custom.save()

            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors, usercustom.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        usercustom = UserCustom()

    return render(request,'form.html',{'user_form':user_form,'usercustom':usercustom,'registered':registered})
```